# All possible unique pair combinations of gamete positions

Tags: r, combinations, bioinformatics

I have some gamete data in the following format:

```
Ind Letter Place Position
1   A      19    23
2   B      19    23
3   B      19    23
4   B      19    23
1   B      19    34
2   A      19    34
3   B      19    34
4   B      19    34
1   C      19    52
2   T      19    52
3   C      19    52
4   T      19    52
1   T      33    15
2   T      33    15
3   T      33    15
4   C      33    15
1   C      33    26
2   T      33    26
3   T      33    26
4   C      33    26
```

dput of data:

```
structure(list(Ind = c(1L,2L,3L,4L,1L,2L,3L,4L,1L,2L,3L,4L,1L,2L,3L,4L,1L,2L,3L,4L),
      Letter = structure(c(1L,2L,2L,2L,2L,1L,2L,2L,3L,4L,3L,4L,4L,4L,4L,3L,3L,4L,4L,3L),
                       .Label = c("A","B","C","T"), class="factor"), 
      Place = c(19L,19L,19L,19L,19L,19L,19L,19L,19L,19L,19L,19L,33L,33L,33L,33L,33L,33L,33L,33L),
      Position = c(23L,23L,23L,23L,34L,34L,34L,34L,52L,52L,52L,52L,15L,15L,15L,15L,26L,26L,26L,26L)),
    .Names = c("Ind","Letter","Place","Position"),
    class="data.frame", row.names = c(NA,-20L))
```

I need to pair and combine them, so I get all possible unique combinations with reference to Position within a pair. I have another data-file, that contains information on the pairs, and they are paired with reference to Place. So in this file I may see, that Place 19+Place 33 is a pair, and I want the following result:

```
Ind Letter Place Position Ind Letter Place Position
1   A      19    23       1   T      33    15
2   B      19    23       2   T      33    15
3   B      19    23       3   T      33    15
4   B      19    23       4   C      33    15

1   A      19    23       1   C      33    26
2   B      19    23       2   T      33    26
3   B      19    23       3   T      33    26
4   B      19    23       4   C      33    26

1   B      19    34       1   T      33    15
2   A      19    34       2   T      33    15
3   B      19    34       3   T      33    15
4   B      19    34       4   C      33    15

1   B      19    34       1   C      33    26
2   A      19    34       2   T      33    26
3   B      19    34       3   T      33    26
4   B      19    34       4   C      33    26

1   C      19    52       1   T      33    15
2   T      19    52       2   T      33    15
3   C      19    52       3   T      33    15
4   T      19    52       4   C      33    15

1   C      19    52       1   C      33    26
2   T      19    52       2   T      33    26
3   C      19    52       3   T      33    26
4   T      19    52       4   C      33    26
```

In this case *unique* means that A1:A2 is equal to A2:A1.
The reason I want to do this, is because I want to do a Four-Gamete-Test on the pairs, to the see if all possible combinations of Letter is existent. So e.g. for the last combined pair above, we have the letter-pairs CC, TT, CT, TC, so this combined pair will pass the FGT.

I have tried to do the combining with `expand.grid`, as it seems this is quite close to what I want. However, when I require all combination of data$Position, I lose the information for Ind, Letter, and Place. Also the output includes non-unique pairs.

Can anyone point me to a tool, that is closer to what I want? Or give me some guidelines on how to modify `expand.grid`, to get what I need.
Should you be aware of a tool, that actually does the Four-Gamete-Test, or something similar, then that would of course also be interesting for me to look at.

Comment: Could you pls dput the data frames that you have. I would suggest you create a key for the paired Places, and then do a cross join.

Comment: I am not sure how to dput the data. I am assuming that you want this, so you can import the data, is that right?
I have the data as .csv, but I do not know how to attach this to the question.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't clear: I can do the dput function, but I am not sure on what to do with the resulting file. Do I just paste it into my question or do I need to attach as a file somehow?

Comment: @Hjalte just paste it in

Comment: Okay, thank you, I have done so.

Comment: Googling for 'R "four-gamete test"' gives 5960 results.

Comment: Is this a duplicate of [Four-Gamete-Test in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28988469/four-gamete-test-r)? If not, can you tell us how it differs?

Comment: If you want to generate unique combinations of rows, do `expand.grid` on the vector of row-indices `1:nrow(data)`, not on the values of one of the columns (`data$Position`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `expand.grid` but not directly on the `Position` column. The idea is to find all combinations of the "quartets" (unique Positions):

```
pair <- c(19, 33)

df1 <- df1[df1$Place %in% pair, ]
split1 <- split( df1, df1$Position)

vec1 <- unique(df1$Position[df1$Place == pair[1]])
vec2 <- unique(df1$Position[df1$Place == pair[2]])

combin_num <- expand.grid(vec2, vec1)[,2:1]

do.call( 
  rbind,
  lapply(seq_len(nrow(combin_num)), function(i){
    cbind( split1[[as.character(combin_num[i,1])]], 
           split1[[as.character(combin_num[i,2])]]  )
  })
)[,]
```

Result:

```
#       Ind Letter Place Position Ind.1 Letter.1 Place.1 Position.1
#   1     1      A    19       23     1        T      33         15
#   2     2      B    19       23     2        T      33         15
#   3     3      B    19       23     3        T      33         15
#   4     4      B    19       23     4        C      33         15
#   5     1      A    19       23     1        C      33         26
#   6     2      B    19       23     2        T      33         26
#   7     3      B    19       23     3        T      33         26
#   8     4      B    19       23     4        C      33         26
#   51    1      B    19       34     1        T      33         15
#   61    2      A    19       34     2        T      33         15
#   71    3      B    19       34     3        T      33         15
#   81    4      B    19       34     4        C      33         15
#   52    1      B    19       34     1        C      33         26
#   62    2      A    19       34     2        T      33         26
#   72    3      B    19       34     3        T      33         26
#   82    4      B    19       34     4        C      33         26
#   9     1      C    19       52     1        T      33         15
#   10    2      T    19       52     2        T      33         15
#   11    3      C    19       52     3        T      33         15
#   12    4      T    19       52     4        C      33         15
#   91    1      C    19       52     1        C      33         26
#   101   2      T    19       52     2        T      33         26
#   111   3      C    19       52     3        T      33         26
#   121   4      T    19       52     4        C      33         26
```